# Have a global variable change only per server by command discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am currently trying to create a quiz bot in discord and right now I'm looking for a way (or an alternative) to have global variables change only per server by command. This is what my code looks like:

```
var = 0
@client.command()
async def question1(ctx):
    global var
    if var == 0:
      var = 1
       try:
          ...
    else:
      await ctx.send("A round has already begun.")

@client.command()
async def question2(ctx):
    global var
    if var == 0:
      var = 1
       try:
          ...
    else:
      await ctx.send("A round has already begun.")

@client.command()
async def question3(ctx):
    global var
    if var == 0:
      var = 1
       try:
          ...
    else:
      await ctx.send("A round has already begun.")

@client.command()
async def stopg(ctx):
  if var = 1:
    var = 0
    await ctx.send("Round has been stopped")
  else:
    await ctx.send("You can only use this command if a round is running.")
```

I use loops to send my sets of questions since they come in different parts, and there are multiple commands since there are different categories and parameters. All my commmands are dependent on the global variable but once I tried using commands in two different servers, it would say that a round has already begun. I've searched a bit and found that using a class function would be helpful, but I have no idea how I should apply it.

I wrote the code on a whim so I apologize if there is anything wrong, feel free to mention it. Any answer will be appreciated, thanks~.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way would be using a dictionary, the key being the guild ID, and the value the actual variable

```py
variables = {}  # use `collections.defaultdict` for a dictionary with a default value

@client.command()
async def question1(ctx):
    var = variables.get(ctx.guild.id, 0) 
    if var == 0:
        variables[ctx.guild.id] = 1
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much~ It actually didn't work at first when I used `variables[ctx.guild.id]` but I simpy changed the line to `var`. I'm not sure yet how it bad it will affect my code but this was super useful thanks~~!